# Socket.io NOT emitting messages to XHR Clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Okay, so I've got a Node.js server running Socket.io. It uses a RedisStore so I can have multiple Node.js server instances. Everything works exactly as it should with the exception that I can't emit a message from the server to my XHR-Polling client. It works in fine in the following situations:

- When testing the client in Chrome and use Websockets it works great.
- When connected to the same Node server instance.

  - It should work regardless of which instance its on since I'm using the RedisStore.